# submodule of module not working in gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a root project `gradletinker` with sub-module `xt-domain-layer`. The `settings.gradle` of `gradletinker` is:

```
rootProject.name = 'gradletinker'
include 'xt-domain-layer'
```

The `xt-domain-layer` also contains a submodule called `xt-web`. The `settings.gradle` of `xt-domain-layer` is:

```
  rootProject.name = 'xt-domain-layer'
  include 'xt-web'
```

Now from the root project `graldetinker` when I run `\gradletinker>gradlew projects` I do not getting the submodule `xt-web` listed

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Root project             
------------------------------------------------------------

Root project 'gradletinker'
\--- Project ':xt-domain-layer'


\gradletinker>gradlew -q :xt-domain-layer:projects

------------------------------------------------------------
Project :xt-domain-layer
------------------------------------------------------------

Project ':xt-domain-layer'
No sub-projects
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: Why do you not have an `include...` line  in your xt-domain-layer's setting.gradle? You add a submodule using the include line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#standardLayouts) docs. I only need a single settings.gradle file at the root level.

`rootProject.name = 'gradletinker'
include 'xt-domain-layer:xt-web`

So removed the settings.gradle files and added the following in settings.gradle at the root level.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Root project 'gradletinker'
\--- Project ':xt-domain-layer'
     \--- Project ':xt-domain-layer:xt-web'
```

Answer (score 1):

You use settings.gradle to add sub-projects to a gradle projects. The mechanism to add it is:

```
include 'subproject-folder-name'
```

or alternatively, if the subproject is located in some arbitrary location:

```
include ":subProj"
project(":subProj").projectDir = file("path/to/subproject")
```

In your case, add to `xt-domain-layer` settings.gradle:

```
include 'xt-web'
```

Comment: sorry I missed to copy that. I have updated the question

Comment: Hmm, is there a reason why you have two settings.gradle files? Instead of organizing all three projects in the root settings.gralde? Your setup isn't working for me at all. gradle in the root project cannot find the project 2 levels down..

Comment: what version of gradle are you using?

Comment: I am using gradle 2.4. Its just a sample for another multimodule project which need to have a module similar to `xt-domain-layer` which should have another set of submodules similar to `xt-web`